# Resultado de 2 queries fetch_assoc en un array

Tags: php, sql

La idea es obtener los valores que contienen el resultado de dos queries y almacenarlos en un solo array, ya que este se trata después y se hace otra query con el mismo.Os pongo en situación:

```
$comprobar_reservas_inicio = $sql->ejecutar_consulta(" SELECT id_producto,fecha_inicio,fecha_fin FROM reservas_prueba 
                  WHERE fecha_inicio >= '2016-10-13'" );

$comprobar_reservas_fin = $sql->ejecutar_consulta(" SELECT id_producto,fecha_inicio,fecha_fin FROM reservas_prueba 
                  WHERE fecha_fin <= '2016-11-11'" );

$barcos_no_disponibles = array();

$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comprobar_reservas_inicio))
                            {
                               $barcos_no_disponibles = $row['id_producto'];

                            }



                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comprobar_reservas_fin))
                            {
                               $barcos_no_disponibles = $row['id_producto'];
                            }

            $comprobar_flota = $sql->ejecutar_consulta("SELECT * FROM flota
         WHERE FLOTAID NOT IN ('$barcos_no_disponibles') ");
```

La variable `$i`, quiero utilizarla para acceder a la posición correcta del nuevo array,que irá incrementándose,pero,no consigo que funcione correctamente y quede almacenado en un solo array.

Gracias por adelantado.

Edit.Doy más detalles..

```
//Las dos variables se pasan por POST,desde un formulario con campos DATE..

$fecha_inicio = $_POST['fecha_inicio'];
$fecha_fin = $_POST['fecha_fin'];

//Mediante una función obtengo los dias existentes entre esos dos

function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo = null)
{
    // takes two dates formatted as YYYY-MM-DD and creates an
    // inclusive array of the dates between the from and to dates.
    $aryRange=array();

    $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
    $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

    if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom)
    {
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry
        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
        {
            $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
            array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        }
    }
    return $aryRange;
}

//Guardo los valores de las fechas en una cadena

$array_rango_fechas = createDateRangeArray($fecha_inicio,$fecha_fin);

$fechas_a_reservar = implode(',' ,$array_rango_fechas );

//Despues con estas fechas,compruebo los datos de los barcos que esten //reservados en dias presentes en el rango

$comprobar_reservas_inicio = $sql->ejecutar_consulta(" SELECT id_producto FROM reservas_prueba WHERE fecha_inicio IN  ('$fechas_a_reservar') " );

$comprobar_reservas_fin    = $sql->ejecutar_consulta(" SELECT id_producto FROM reservas_prueba WHERE fecha_fin IN  ('$fechas_a_reservar') " );

//y después,gurado los IDs de los barcos YA RESERVADOS,para excluirlos de la //consulta de barcos disponibles

$barcos_no_disponibles = array();

        $i = 0;

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comprobar_reservas_inicio))
            {
               $barcos_no_disponibles = $row['id_producto'].",";

            }


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comprobar_reservas_fin))
            {
               $barcos_no_disponibles .= $row['id_producto'];
            }


/---COMPROBAR flota con ID (?)
$comprobar_flota = $sql->ejecutar_consulta("SELECT * FROM flota WHERE FLOTAID NOT 
                IN ('$barcos_no_disponibles') ");

            $array_flota = array();
            $i = 0;


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($comprobar_flota )) {

                $array_flota[$i]['FLOTAID']         = $row['FLOTAID'];
                $array_flota[$i]['NOMBRE']          = $row['NOMBRE'];
                $array_flota[$i]['CARACTERISTICAS'] = $row['CARACTERISTICAS'];
                $array_flota[$i]['EQUIPAMIENTO']    = $row['EQUIPAMIENTO'];

                $i++;
            }


//por ultimo devuelvo los valores al script php que llama a este
//de esta forma debido a ser una petición AJAX
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($array_flota);
exit;
```

El script no acaba de devolver lo que deseo..
muestra una lista de barcos disponibles según las fechas especificadas,pero como decia antes,no esta correctamente guardado en un solo array,por lo que se aplican solamente los ultimos cambios y se devuelve una parte de los datos.

Comment: Si pudieras dar un poco mas detalles de lo que quieres que sea tu resultado final, a simple vista se puede decir que incrementes la variable ´$i´ y ya.

Comment: No se te hara mas facil hacer un BETWEEN en tu consulta en ves de dos?

Comment: Gracias chicos,he conseguido avanzar y salir del paso,aunque solamente sigue teniendo en cuenta la ultima reserva de barcos,por lo que solo excluye según esa..

Answer (score 1):

Usa union
SELECT id_producto,fecha_inicio,fecha_fin FROM reservas_prueba 
          WHERE fecha_inicio >= '2016-10-13' **union**
SELECT id_producto,fecha_inicio,fecha_fin FROM reservas_prueba 
          WHERE fecha_fin <= '2016-11-11'"

o solo haz una query, entiendo que seleccionas un rango de fechas WHERE fecha_inicio >= '2016-10-13' **OR** fecha_fin <= '2016-11-11' 
Primero prueba tu query directamente en la DB. Si el dato de la fecha lo guarda la db en automatico procura usar where date(fecha_fin) = "2016-10-10"

Comment: Mucho mejor,gracias! Ahora el problema es "Array to String conversion",al hacer la ultima consulta con el array ya lleno de los datos necesarios.Edit: ha sido al modificar $barcos_disponibles a $barcos_disponibles[$i] dentro del while,ya que me quiero asegurar que se guardan todos los valores